# Usar directamente findViewById()

Tags: android

¿ Hay desventajas de rendimiento u otro tipo al usar directamente `findViewById()` sin un objeto ?

Quiero decir, en vez de:

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ /*código*/ });
```

Usar solamente:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){ /*código*/ });
```

Comment: y si desea manipular dicho botón como sería ? tendrías que hacer el findViewById?  :]

Comment: Las llamadas a `findViewById` tienen cierto impacto más o menos costoso en el rendimiento... he leído algunas críticas muy negativas al respecto por lo que a mi parecer, no goza de muy buena fama entre los desarrolladores de Android. A simple vista sería mejor usar tu botón con una variable... (en caso de que no ganes en rendimiento, ganas al menos en claridad de código) y si lo vas a usar en varias partes de tu código, declarar dicha variable como un miembro de la clase. No obstante, es bueno saber que hay otras alternativas...

Comment: ... tales como  [No More findViewById](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885), también existe  [@InjectView](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/android-findviewbyid-vs-injectview/) y quizá más alternativas. Creo que `findViewById`, tarde o temprano, terminará siendo obsoleto y se optará por otros usos más eficaces.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios. Respondiendo a Dev. Joel, si deseara manipular el botón usaría `((Button) view)`.

Answer (score 1):

No hay inconvenientes en mi opinión, pero te recomendaría usarlo desde la variable creada, ya que estás almacenando la referencia del botón que de cierta forma te facilitaría en caso de que lo requieras para implementar otros eventos como `onKey()`, `onLongClick()`, `onKeyDown()` etc, sin tener que volver a invocarlo por findViewById.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola. De hecho mi duda era específicamente con el caso en que solamente se implementara el evento onClick() y no hubiera que volver a hacer referencia al botón. Había leído antes sobre el peso de usar el findViewById() pero, en el caso que explico, solamente se usa una vez y con un solo evento, entonces pensé que me podría ahorrar la primera línea. Pero en realidad optaré por declarar las variables al comienzo, por considerarlo una mejor práctica (así puedo conocerlas todas a simple vista en el comienzo de la clase). Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No hay desventajas tan marcadas para añadir el `OnClickListener` anónimo *(en mi opinión)* , la primera opción se realiza simplemente para tener una referencia a dicho `View` para más adelante si se desea manipular o realizar alguna otra acción con este elemento pueda acceder.

La pregunta que salta a la vista sería , ¿Y sí desea trabajar con dicho botón para manipular su texto u otra cosa ? , Sí. seguro deberá hacer el `findViewById` nuevamente. he ahí la desventaja.

Al final la primera opción solo es un concepto de variable , que se usa para almacenar una referencia a un `View`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta.

Si deseo trabajar con el botón para manipular su texto u otra cosa usaría `((Button) view)`. Por ejemplo, para cambiar su texto `((Button) view).setText("texto");`.

Comment: Si hubiese más de un botón, igualmente se estaría cambiando el texto él mismo (él es el `view` que viene como parámetro).

Si se va a realizar una simple acción con el botón, no le veo más conveniencia a una u otra opción, simplemente usas o no la variable.

Comment: Realiza un casting innecesario. Para mi y para la mayoría de los desarrolladores de Android prefieren variables. Es todo espero haya ayudado, saludos

Comment: Ok, solo daba mi opinión. Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: @felipe no pasa nada , lo ideal sería las variables como consejo final .Saludos.

Comment: A mi no me aparece con -1 tu respuesta, me aparece en 0. Pero la de Jorgesys sí me aparece con -1, y no le veo motivo ni puedo calificar para hacer algo.

Comment: Ok, yo por ahora no puedo calificar por mi reputación baja. Ojalá el que hace la pregunta pudiera dar algun tipo de califición para reflejar si le sirvió la respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso si quieres asignar una propiedad o listener a tu vista, no existe ninguna diferencia o desventaja:

Opción 1)

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ /*código*/ });
```

Opción 2)

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){ /*código*/ });
```

Incluso usar varias ocasiones  `findViewById(R.id.elemento)` no provoca problemas en performance porque solo obtiene la referencia de la vista en un layout

---

Pero que sucede si realizando la opción 2, también necesitas la referencia de la vista en otras partes de tu clase, en este caso tendrías que buscar la referencia de la vista varias veces mediante `findViewById()`.

Por esta razón, regularmente se define una variable del tipo de vista:

```
private Button button1;
```

y se obtiene la referencia:

```
button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

para ser usada en otras partes de tu aplicación.